# Visited input width

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class, visited

I have an input field 400px width. When I hover it, width will increase on 500px, when I focus it, width will stay increased on 500px. Than I write down some text, click away and input field come back to 400px width. I want to stay input field on width 500px after writing down some text into the field and click away, or press TAB.

I have it like this:

```
input { background-color:#fff; width:400px; ....... } 
input:hover { opacity:0.9; filter:alpha(opacity=90); width:500px;} 
input:focus {  color:#ff6b4f; box-shadow: 0 0 8px #fff; width:500px;} 
input:visited {  color:#ff6b4f; box-shadow: 0 0 8px #fff; width:500px;}
```

This does not work. I do not know how can I do that correctly.

Comment: The pseudo-class `:visited` works just for links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you should use javascript. You can handle `blur` event of your input and check if it's empty or not. If it's not add some additional class which change width to 500px;

You can see working (jQuery) example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cF28Q/)

Also `:visited` pseudo-class works **only** for links.

Comment: Maaaaaaaaaaaan you are awesome!! thank you so much! ;) this really helps me. You wrote it absolutely correct and complete so I just copy it and understand it. THANK YOU AGAIN!

Answer (score 1):

The `:visited` attribute only applies to links, so you'll have to use Javascript instead:

```
CSS:
input {
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:0.25em 0.5em;
}
input:hover, input:focus, input.visited {
    width:300px;
}

HTML:
<form>
    <input name="x" onchange="this.className=(this.value=='')?'':'visited';" />
</form>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e77CG/

Comment: thank you for respond! I understand your solution too and will use it later on something else. Thank you.